# WCF Timeout Longer than Timeout Value Set

Tags: wcf, timeout

Scenario:  WCF service is running.  Client is attempting to connect to it and use a method on the service.  Service hangs for 2-3 minutes before returning a timeout.

All timeout values are set to be 10 seconds.

```
    binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_timeout);
    binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_timeout);
    binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_timeout);
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_timeout);
```

Additionally the client has its InnerChannel.OperationTimeout set to TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_timeout) as well.

_timeout comes from the app.config file and is the value "10".

What I expect is that if there is a timeout that it takes 10 seconds to resolve, and not 120-180 seconds, which is what it is doing now.

The connection appears to be fine, its calling the method that intermittently fails and times out 120-180 seconds later.

Upon trying to send the command immediately after the timeout (repeating the call basically) it sends and receives just fine.

What am I missing here?  What else needs set to make sure the client is not sitting for 2-3 minutes before timing out?

All articles that I am finding deal with these five timeout values (Close, Open, Send, Receive, and Operation).

binding is of type BasicHttpBinding.

Comment: Ideally you set a comfortable timeout value on service side, and you can control a lower value on client call. Could share your app.config, specifically the `binding` section and the `endpoint` configuration?

Comment: Ricardo, there was nothing set on the service end.  After setting timeouts on the service end, the problem appears to have resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that both service side and client side require these timeouts.  There was no timeout value placed on the service end.  Once placed, the problem appears to have reconciled itself.

Comment: Well, the client should be able to time out before the service times out if it was set to a lessor time out value.

Comment: The service was using default timeout values.  the client was set to timeout after 10 seconds but the service was not honoring that and it was waiting 2-3 minutes.

Comment: are you sure that the client is not using the same binding as the service?

Comment: They had different entries in their app.configs.